# Filter hosts in ansible by multiple value in a tag

Tags: filter, ansible, tags, key-value

I would like to filter hosts from ec2.py script using multiple values inside tag from AWS

For now instances has a tag 
Service: app1:app2:app3

And I would like to filter hosts attribute to only by executed in instances with app1 for example

ansible-playbook -i ./ec2.py --extra-vars="env=beta service=app1" test_inv.yml

innside test_inv.yml

> - hosts: "tag_Environment_{{env}}:&tag_Service_{{service}}"

How can I pass the tag to filter only one of the values inside tag?

Ansible not detects the value If I have app1-b:app2:app3

Doing tests I see

> ansible-playbook -i ./ec2.py --extra-vars="env=beta service=*app1*"
>   test_inv.yml

Detects the value, but which special characters can be used to separate tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems how EC2.py script converts any special character into "_" allowing filtering using * but yo can't use any other character because first is converted.